# R language: What does the result of the augmented Dickey Fuller test mean?

Tags: r, time-series

I've seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55805/how-do-you-interpret-results-from-unit-root-tests), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57807/confusion-with-augmented-dickey-fuller-test) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213551/how-is-the-augmented-dickey-fuller-test-adf-table-of-critical-values-calculate), but none explain properly, the interpretation of the basic output that R shows. Also, some of the other questions about Dickey Fuller test didn't even receive answers, so I'm asking here.

Eg: From [this tutorial](https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-forecasting-with-arima-in-r-learn-data-science-tutorials), it says the null hypothesis is rejected, but I don't see anything in the output that indicates that. If I'm supposed to take a hint from the p value, then how do I know what is the cutoff limit considered for p?

```
count_d1 = diff(deseasonal_cnt, differences = 1) 
plot(count_d1)
adf.test(count_d1, alternative = "stationary")
```

> Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
>
> data:  count_d1 Dickey-Fuller = -9.9255, Lag order = 8, p-value = 0.01
>   alternative hypothesis: stationary

In other tutorials I've seen such outputs where they conclude that the time series is stationary or non-stationary by looking at the `adt.test` output, but they mention nothing about how they came to that conclusion.

So how do I know if the null hypothesis was rejected or not? Isn't it possible to have an if statement like:
`if adf.test(count_d1, alternative = "stationary")==TRUE, 
print("null hypo true"); else print("null hypo rejected");`?

Comment: If people are judging statistical tests to be "significant" without mentioning their decision rule, I would usually guess that they are using `p < 0.05` as their threshold for that decision. That's a pretty widely used convention (although ideally you would at least mention that that is what your are doing).

Comment: (1) `library(tseries)`? Please be explicit with non-base package requirements. (2) `if (...==TRUE)` is meaningless, suggest either `if (...)` or `if (isTRUE(...))` (which is slightly different and can be more robust). (3) The p-value doesn't automatically reject or fail-to-reject a test; what you use as a cutoff is something *you* determine before beginning the test. This specific output isn't telling you to reject or not, it is just reporting the p-value, nothing more.

Comment: Yes, it's `library(tseries)`. The code is from the tutorial I linked to. So I can safely assume that the author of the tutorial is probably using 0.05 as the p cut-off value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Walter Enders Applied Econometric Time Series 3e, 2010 for the theory. There is no strict rule of an "cut-off value". Nevertheless, a value of 0.05 is generally considered appropriate to discard a null hypothesis. (Of course, lower p-values support this thesis all the more credibly)